# Divide each element of xts object by corresponding value from bigger xts object

Tags: r, division, xts

How can I make R take an xts object and divide each value of it to a corresponding (by date) value from other, bigger, xts object?

Suppose I have an xts object with sales in currency A in one xts object:

```
2018-01-01 200.0 

2018-01-04 400.0
```

And I have currency exchange rate in other xts object:

```
2018-01-01 5.0

2018-01-02 5.5

2018-01-03 5.7

2018-01-04 6.0

2018-01-05 5.9
```

I want to divide each of sales values by currency rate at this day and get a resulting xts object like:

```
2018-01-01 40.0

2018-01-04 66.7
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the objects (so that the dates align) and then divide the columns.

```
library(xts)
sales <- xts(c(200, 400), as.Date(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-04')))
exchange <- xts(c(5, 5.5, 5.7, 6.0, 5.9),
            as.Date(c('2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05')))

merged <- merge(sales, exchange, all=c(TRUE,FALSE))
converted <- merged$sales / merged$exchange
converted
#           sales
#2018-01-01   200
#2018-01-04   400
```